# Problem with polyglossia and MinionPro

Tags: fonts, luatex, polyglossia, small-caps, minionpro

I have a problem with small caps not showing correctly when loading `polyglossia`. I am trying to use `polyglossia` with `classicthesis`, which I know is unsupported, but the same problem appears when loading `MinionPro`, `polyglossia` and using small caps. MWE:

```
  \documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \usepackage{classicthesis}
  \begin{document}
  \chapter{Foo}
  \section{Bar}
  \subsection{Baz}
  \end{document}
```

Here Bar is not set in small caps. MWE2:

```
  \documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \usepackage{MinionPro}
  \begin{document}
  \textsc{Should be small caps}
  \end{document}
```

Now I do get font substitution warnings but these don't make sense. Why would polyglossia change the font encoding and is there a way to stop it?

Comment: If I use `\setmainfont{Minion Pro}` instead of `\usepackage{MinionPro}` (that I don't have), small caps are typeset correctly.

Comment: In the minimal sample this works for me too, but I get a different font and getting this to work with my actual document does not seem to work

Comment: polyglossia loads fontspec (which is recommended if you use lualatex). Fontspec changes the font encoding to an encoding suitable for an unicode engine like lualatex but this clashes with minionpro.sty (which is meant for pdflatex). If you want to switch to lualatex you will have to change your font setup - and you should load polyglossia *after* packages which perhaps revert to a pdflatex setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`polyglossia` loads `fontspec` (which is recommended if you use lualatex). `fontspec` changes the font encoding to an encoding suitable for an unicode engine like lualatex but this clashes with `minionpro.sty` (which is meant for pdflatex).

If you want to switch to lualatex you will have to change your font setup - and you should always load `polyglossia` *after* packages which perhaps reverts to a pdflatex setup.